# How do I build a static C++ openmpi application?

Tags: c++, ubuntu, gcc, compilation, openmpi

I am trying to do is produce a static MPI executable for Linux machines. The source code is written in C++. When I compile serial versions of the code, with `gcc -static`, and run `ldd` on the executable it shows no libraries.

However, when I try this with MPI, there are certain libraries that are not being statically linked. I have built my openmpi on my machine with see below shell commands. I also see that the exact same libraries that are not statically linking with the executable are not statically linking to the openmpi build. At the end of the openmpi build, I get

```sh
/home/bevan/Downloads/openmpi-4.0.1/opal/.libs/libopen-pal.a(dl_dlopen_module.o): In function `dlopen_open':
dl_dlopen_module.c:(.text+0x413): warning: Using 'dlopen' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking
/home/bevan/Downloads/openmpi-4.0.1/orte/.libs/libopen-rte.a(plm_rsh_module.o): In function `setup_launch':
plm_rsh_module.c:(.text+0xca2): warning: Using 'getpwuid' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking
/home/bevan/Downloads/openmpi-4.0.1/opal/.libs/libopen-pal.a(if.o): In function `opal_ifaddrtoname':
if.c:(.text+0x1e4): warning: Using 'getaddrinfo' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking
/home/bevan/Downloads/openmpi-4.0.1/orte/.libs/libopen-rte.a(ras_slurm_module.o): In function `init':
ras_slurm_module.c:(.text+0x6e4): warning: Using 'gethostbyname' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking
/home/bevan/Downloads/openmpi-4.0.1/opal/.libs/libopen-pal.a(evutil.o): In function `evutil_unparse_protoname':
/home/bevan/Downloads/openmpi-4.0.1/opal/mca/event/libevent2022/libevent/evutil.c:758: warning: Using 'getprotobynumber' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking
```

The sort of command chain I feel I should be using is,

```sh
tar -xvf openmpi-4.0.1
cd ./openmpi-4.0.1
./configure --prefix="$HOME/.openmpi" --without-memory-manager CXX=g++ CC=gcc LDFLAGS=--static --disable-shared --enable-static
make
sudo make install
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.openmpi/bin"
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:$HOME/.openmpi/lib/"
cd application/directory/build
cmake ..
make application
```

I would like to be able to run `ldd application` after compiling with MPI and have no dynamically linked libraries associated with the application.